# IV and salt key found in shared preferences of mobile application

Tags: android

What can i do with these vectors? Is it a finding if i found in shared preferences file of a android mobile application

Comment: IV and salt are unsed interchangeably. Are you referring to IV/Salt and Key? or only IV/Salt??

Comment: @ShivSahni Honestly, I've never heard IV used interchangeably with salt. They have completely different purposes. A salt is designed to defeat rainbow table and other precomputation attacks, and make parallel brute force attacks slower. An IV is used to ensure the starting block is unique between encryptions, even if the "real" first block and key are the same as encrypting another file.

Answer (score 3):

An initialisation vector is  a random piece of data that is passed to the encryption function, typically it helps ensure that the same piece of data encrypted twice will yield a different result. Often it is preprended to the ciphertext and your decryption method will know the first x bytes are the IV to use for the decryption.  In a correctly designed system there is no reason for the IV to be kept secret.  There's a good discussion on that on Crypto Exchange [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37662/in-which-cases-should-the-iv-be-kept-secret/37667)

A salt is used in hashing operations, it is random data appended to a piece of plain text prior to hashing so the same piece of data hashed twice will not yield the same result.

What can you do with these? Not a lot probably. Given the ciphertext, salt and IV, you are still unlikely to determine the plain text if a robust encryption method is correctly implemented. To decrypt you still need the key which is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you won't be able to do much with just these bits of information. In order to explot the IV or the salt, you need to know what cyphertext have resulted from encryption using these values, and you would still have to figure out the corresponding key.

However, the fact that you found them inside the application's binary could suggest that the authors are doing something a bit reckless. These values could be used repeatedly in, respectively, encryption and hashing functions (further analysis of the binary would most probably yield information on whether or not this is the case).

As mentioned in [iainpb's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/180302/103021), the IV is there to prevent identical plaintexts to have identical corresponding cyphertexts. There is therefore an underlying requirement that the IV *must* change for every encryption of every plaintext, even if you decide to, or have to communicate it publicly afterwards. Reusing an IV for multiple encryptions does result in identical plaintexts having identical cyphertexts, thus defeating the purpose entirely. What would a statically stored IV in a binary used for? If you could identify the nature of the data encrypted using this IV, you could mount a [chosen-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) to recover the key.

Regarding the salt, much of the same can be said. Again as iainpb mentions, using salts you would not have identical plaintexts have identical correspondig hashes, but with the requirement that a different salt is used for each hashing. If salts are reused, there are useless in preventing chosen-plaintext attacks.

That said, if the authors bothered to store "IV" and "salt" in the binary, there is a non-zero chance that "key" may be in there too in some form... or it could all just be a false lead and these IV and salt values aren't used for anything and are just code remnants.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Key and IV you can use it to **decrypt the encrypted text**.

If the mobile application is using it to encrypt sensitive data such as local data storage, input parameter to HTTP requests etc. then you can use it to decrypt the same by using the same algorithm and configuration that was used for encryption.

Comment: However, you don't have the key. As stated in the question, you have only salt. The salt is not a key, this is a mistake in the question.

Comment: @Vilican I read it IV/Salt and Key. IV/Salt is not considered as sensitive data. Without the encryption key cracking decryption is like breaking the encryption algorithm itself.